# Проверка на null RedBean php

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp, null

Подскажите как сделать проверку на 0 что бы не допустить публикацию пустых строк

```
<?php
$sql = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM users');
     foreach ($sql as $row) echo
    '<div class="numbers">', '<div class="auto1">', '<div class="auto2">', $row['search1'], '</div>', '</div>',
    '<div class="own1">', '<div class="own2">', $row['tel'], '</div>', '</div>', '</div>', '<br>';
?>
```

собственно сейчас если *$row['search1']* = **null** то эта запись все равно видна , и рядом с ней написан только *$row['tel']* телефон, как сделать чтобы пустой *search1* и его *tel* не публиковался? Пробовал делать сам и получилось что если хоть 1 строка = 0 то не публикуется вообще ничего а не конкретно 1 пустая строка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Самый правильный способ: Выбрать из БД сразу только те записи, где `search1 IS NOT NULL` (или те, которые нужно выводить)
2. В цикле проверять, если `null`, то продолжить цикл

   ```
    foreach ($sql as $row)  {
        if (is_null($row['search1'] ))
            continue;

        echo .....
    }
   ```

Comment: Не сработало, и 0 и null и даже пустая строка - все равно публикуется .

Comment: @Interceptor абсолютно неправда! http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/785675132f8d73713646075207a519aa7f12c9e9  Значит там не null.

Comment: Прошу прощения, там действительно был не null, не досмотрел . Спасибо, все работает)